# How to include a inc file configuration in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm setting up a new test in my legacy PHP code, I have a inc file and I want to include in my bootstrap file, but after a execute my phpunit in the terminal, it shows me only the code and he can't interpreter the file as a PHP code

I use PHP 5.3 with phpunit 4.8,

config.inc example:

```
<?
// Login
define("CONNEXION_LOGIN","login");

// Password
define("CONNEXION_PWD","pwd");
```

bootstrap.php example:

```
<?php

require(__DIR__. '\..\config\file.inc');
```

there is any solution to include the inc file, I can't change the extension of the file, because the project is very big and the inc file is included in a lot of file of the project.

Update 1:
i have did a mistake i forgot to enable the short_open_tag in my php.ini
thank you to @mangus eriksson

Comment: Why are you calling the file `.inc` instead of `.php`? Isn't it better to give the file the correct extension to explicitly say what type of file it is? _Side notes:_ You should use `<?php` instead of the short open tag `<?`. Short open tags have been disabled as default since a bunch of versions back. You should also upgrade your PHP version. 5.3 haven't been supported in years.

Comment: Yess, this the correct response, i forgot to modify my php.ini, i must to modify the short_open_tag from Off to ON , thank you :)

Comment: i can't upgrade my version of PHP right now, because this is complicated , this a big project need a entire renovation :)